# Geometric Interpretation of $\operatorname{Span}\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3},\vec{v_4}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ \vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3},\vec{v_4}$ be non zero vectors in $\Bbb R^4$ such that the solution to the system $[\vec{v_1} \ \vec{v_2}\ \vec{v_3} \ \vec{v_4}| \ 0]$ is a hyperplane containing 3 vectors. What would be the geometrical interpretation of $\operatorname{Span}\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3},\vec{v_4}\}$? Would it be the solution space, and thus a 3D "cube" that extends?

Comment: A hyperplane is a subspace, and any subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ contains either $1$ vector or infinitely many.  It doesn't make sense to say that your solution "is a hyperplane containing 3 vectors"

Comment: By the rank nullity theorem, the dimension of $\operatorname{Span}\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3},\vec{v_4}\}$ is $1$, which is to say that it is of "complementary dimension" to your solution space.